# Retrieving data from an array, starting with specific nth item in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops, foreach

I have these arrays inside Controller:

```
Public function home(){
     $images = [
          'img/image1.jpg',
          'img/image2.jpg',
          'img/image3.jpg',
          'img/image4.jpg',
          'img/image5.jpg',
          'img/image6.jpg'
     ];
     $rep_titles = [
          '外国美女路亚鲈鱼图片合集',
          '对人类有威胁的那些怪鱼 高清钓鱼图片',
          '那些被钓到的长牙的鱼 高清图片',
          '那些钓友去年钓上的巨物 高清图片',
          '垂钓图片 那些痴迷的美女',
          '冒雨征战秘密基地收获鳊鱼大板鲫',
     ],
}
```

and this, inside view:

**1ST Content**

```
@foreach (array_slice($images,0,3) as $keyIndex => $image)
     <div class="r-c-collection-container">
          <div class="img-content">
               <img src="{{ asset( $image ) }}" alt="{{ $image }}">
          </div>
          <div class="r-c-content">
               <a href="#" class="title">{{$rep_titles[$keyIndex]}}</a>
          </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

**2nd Content** (where I want to start on a specific nth-item from the array, 3rd to be specific)

```
@foreach (array_slice($images,3,3) as $keyIndex => $image)
     <div class="r-c-collection-container">
          <div class="img-content">
               <img src="{{ asset( $image ) }}" alt="{{ $image }}">
          </div>
          <div class="r-c-content">
               <a href="#" class="title">{{$rep_titles[$keyIndex]}}</a>
          </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

My problem is that, the items `$rep_titles` on the 2nd content goes back or loops back to the 1st item where the item should start on the 3rd item.  I have no problem with the images because it starts where I want it to be. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I really hope that someone could help me about this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [array_slice doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) you unintentionally have reset the array index to zero. You need an extra fourth parameter (a boolean) to indicate you don't want that reset to take place, like this:

```
@foreach (array_slice($images, 3, 3, true) as $keyIndex => $image) {
    // rest of your code
}
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php:

> **preserve_keys**
>
> Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the integer array indices by default. You can change this behaviour by setting preserve_keys to TRUE. String keys are always preserved, regardless of this parameter.

Comment: Thanks. @Virginia. This may be true at some point but the code you gave did not worked for me, it's returning an error that says {"Undefined offset: 17}.  If I create another set of array, say {$rep_titles2}, it works. But I think it's not right to create another array for the same set of items. Got any more ideas?

Comment: You're welcome @DaveMoreno. I forgot the possibility that your $images array might have a different length. I agree that creating a second array is not ideal, but an other solution doesn't come to my mind yet. Sorry! I hope someone else can point into the direction of a better option for you.